# minikube does not start on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to setup minikube in a VM with ubuntu desktop 20.04 LTS installed, using docker driver.

I've followed the steps [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/), and also taken into consideration the limitations for the docker driver (reported [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9607)), that have to do with runtime security options. And when I try to start minikube the error I get is : Failed to start host: creating host: create: creating: prepare kic ssh: copying pub key.

This is what I have done to have my brand new VM with minikube installed.

1. Install docker
2. Add my user to the docker group, otherwise minkube start would fail because dockerd runs as root (aka Rootless mode in docker terminology).
3. Install kubectl (that is not necessary, but I opted for this instead of the embedded kubectl in minikube)
4. Install minikube

When I start minikube, this is what I get:

```
ubuntuDesktop:~$ minikube start
  minikube v1.16.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=4500MB) ...
✋  Stopping node "minikube"  ...
  Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...
  Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: creating: prepare kic ssh: copying pub key: docker copy /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset051825440 into minikube:/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys, output: lstat /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset051825440: no such file or directory
: exit status 1
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=4500MB) ...
  Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: creating: prepare kic ssh: copying pub key: docker copy /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591 into minikube:/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys, output: lstat /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591: no such file or directory
: exit status 1

❌  Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION: Failed to start host: creating host: create: creating: prepare kic ssh: copying pub key: docker copy /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591 into minikube:/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys, output: lstat /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591: no such file or directory
: exit status 1

  If the above advice does not help, please let us know: 
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

I suspect that the error has to do with the security settings issues with the docker driver, but this seems to be like a dog chasing its tail: if I don't use rootless mode in docker and I attempt to start minikube with sudo (so that docker can also start up with a privileged user), then I get this:

```
ubuntuDesktop:~$ sudo minikube start
[sudo] password for alberto: 
  minikube v1.16.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: virtualbox, none
  The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges.
  If you are running minikube within a VM, consider using --driver=none:
    https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/

❌  Exiting due to DRV_AS_ROOT: The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges.
```

So, or either I am missing something or minikube doesn't work at all with docker driver, which I doubt.

Here is my environment info:

```
ubuntuDesktop:~$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.11
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.12
 Git commit:        dd360c7
 Built:             Mon Jun  8 20:23:26 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.12
  Git commit:       77e06fd
  Built:            Mon Jun  8 20:24:59 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

ubuntuDesktop:~$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.16.0
commit: 9f1e482427589ff8451c4723b6ba53bb9742fbb1-dirty
```

If someone has minikube working on ubuntu 20.04 and could share versions and driver, I would appreciate. with the info in minikube and docker sites I don't know what else to check to make this work.

Comment: Could you try to run `docker system prune`, `minikube delete` and then `minikube start --driver=docker` again ?

Comment: Thanks @mario... That seems to work; at least I can now overcome the point where it previouly got stuck. The key probably was `docker system prune`, which was the only thing I did not try before several times. For me to learn, could you please elaborate on what garbage has cleaned up that was preventing minkube from starting correctly?... If you post that as an answer I will vote for it because it fixed the initial problem.

Comment: ok, I posted it as an answer. As it comes to the detailed explanation what exactly prevented your **minikube** instance from starting, I'm affraid it won't be possible as it can be a different thing in every individual case and once it's already cleaned up it's impossible to debug the specific reason any more. But let me update my answer and provide at least a general explanation.

Comment: Inspecting the docker logs I've seen this: `[ERROR] Failed to start minikube scheduled stop.`... But `kubectl get all -A` is displaying everything up&running... I'll dig into it but everything seems to be working.

Comment: Did you verify the exact date and hour of this entry in docker logs ? I'm just wondering if it's not related with the previous unsuccessful **Minikube** container provisioning.

Comment: yes, it's today @ 11:23 UTC, so 1/2 h ago when I tried your suggestion... weird

Answer (score 51, accepted):

#### Solution:

As I mentioned in my comment you may just need to run:

```
docker system prune
```

then:

```
minikube delete
```

and finally:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

This should help.

#### Explanation:

Although as I already mentioned in my comment, it's difficult to say what was the issue in your specific case, such situation may happen as a consequence of previous unseccessful attempt to run your **Minikube** instance.

It happens sometimes also when different driver is used and it is run as a **VM** and basically deleting such **VM** may help. Usually running `minikube delete && minikube start` is enough.

In this case, when `--driver=docker` is used, your **Minikube** instance is configured as a container in your **docker runtime** but apart from container itself other things like networking or storage are configured.

[`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) command *removes all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.* So what we can say for sure it was one of the above.

Judging by the exact error message:

```
❌  Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION: Failed to start host: creating host: create: creating: prepare kic ssh: copying pub key: docker copy /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591 into minikube:/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys, output: lstat /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591: no such file or directory
: exit status 1
```

I guess it could be simply clearing some `cached` data that helped in your case and removing broken references to non-existing files. The above message explains quite clearly what couldn't be done, namely **docker** couldn't `copy` a `public ssh key` to the destination `minikube:/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys` as the source file `/tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591`, it attempted to copy it from, simply didn't exist. So it's actually very simple to say *what* happend but to be able to tell *why* it happened might require diving a bit deeper in both **Docker** and **Minikube** internals and analyze step by step how **Minikube** instance is provisioned when using `--driver=docker`.

It's a good point that you may try to analyze your **docker** logs but I seriously doubt that you will find there the exact reason why non-existing temporary file `/tmp/tmpf-memory-asset544814591` was referenced or why it didn't exsist.

Comment: ... It turns out that I haven't enough reputation :-(... As soon as I reach 15 I'll get back and vote it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborating the answer... I have now thanks to your hint my first objects created in the minikube "cluster".

Answer (score 19):

`minikube start --force --driver=docker` fixed it for me

Answer (score 15):

The issue is that the `docker` driver should not be used with root privileges. And by default, the docker daemon always runs as the root user. To run the docker daemon not as root user, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the Docker daemon starts, it creates a Unix socket accessible by members of the docker group.

Run the following commands to fix this issue

1. Create the docker group if not exist

> sudo groupadd docker

2. Add user to the docker group

> sudo usermod -aG docker [user]

3. To activate changes to the group

> newgrp docker

4. start minikube cluster

> minikube start

Comment: Not always the right answer. Please, pay attention to step #2 of the original post, with the detailed steps done: that step is, precisely, what you claim will solve the issue, but clearly did not solve mine at that time. I'd stick to Mario's answer below.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me
`minikube start --driver=docker --container-runtime=containerd`

Answer (score 3):

if you use Linux Desktop OS with docker and minikube already installed, just run

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

and restart your computer.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following first:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Then finally:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue when I attempted to install `Minikube` on an `Ubuntu 20.04 system`.

The "docker system prune" didn't help in my case, but I figured out the cause for my issue was that `/var` was mounted with the `nosuid` option and I had to remove that and remount `/var`. The minikube cluster initialization then worked.

I might be too ignorant but I didn't find that info stated as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Restarting** my mac helped me.

I was getting below error earlier:

```
❌  Exiting due to DRV DOCKER NOT RUNNING: Found docker, but the docker service isn't running. Try restarting the docker service.
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

sudo systemctl enable docker

systemctl status docker

sudo systemctl start/stop docker

sudo groupadd docker

sudo usermod -aG docker user_name --- to add the user to docker group.

newgrp docker  -- to activate the grp

minikube start or minikube start --driver=docker   ---to start minikube

Answer (score 0):

On my Raspberry Pi this problem was resolved with:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker
```

Comment: Be aware that this effectively grants all root permissions to $USER

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
minikube delete
```

Then try to delete all docker images with name like `k8s...` and `minikube`:

```
docker rmi <container id> <container id2> <container id3>
```

Finally:

```
minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

On my end just a docker system prune did the job (Ubuntu).
I had a few configurations I did not want to lose on my minikube profile and it recreated the container accordinlgy and booted fine.
So before the minikube profile deletion it is something to try first.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking to see if it's running in Docker desktop on a Mac.   If it is then run the kubectl command.  If that returns the commands screen then you're good to go.