# how to uninstall minikube from ubuntu, i get an 'Unable to load cached images' error

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube

how to completely uninstall minikube from ubuntu 20.04.

i'm getting an error from my current minikube when starting :

`minikube start` 
gets
  `Preparing Kubernetes v1.20.0 on Docker 20.10.0 ...| ❌  Unable to load cached images: loading cached images: stat /home/feiz-nouri/.minikube/cache/images/gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner_v4: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> how to completely uninstall minikube from ubuntu 20.04

First, run `minikube delete` to remove **minikube VM** (or container if run with `docker` driver), **virtual network interfaces** configured on the host machine and all other traces of **minikube** cluster.

Only then you can safely remove its binary. The way how you should do it depends on how you've installed it, but as you can see [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/), there are not so many options.

If you've installed it by running:

```
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

you can simply remove the binary from `/usr/local/bin/minikube` directory as what the above command basically does, is copying the binary to the destination directory. If it's installed in a different directory, you can always check it by running:

```
which minikube
```

If it was installed using `dpkg` package manager:

```
sudo dpkg -i minikube_latest_amd64.deb
```

you can search for it with the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep minikube
```

If it shows you something like:

```
ii    minikube    1.17.1    amd64    Minikube
```

you can completely remove it (with all its configuration files) by running:

```
sudo dpkg --purge minikube
```

Comment: yes it helped uninstalling minikube.

but i still have the same error after reinstalling it !

Comment: Since you're running it with `--driver=docker`, you may also need to run `docker system prune`. Compare with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423698/11714114) answer.

Comment: ~/.kube and ~/.minikube might need to be removed as well.